builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") doesn't get right string .NET 8
I'm creating an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API, and I can't get right connection string for my database to work. If I hardcode the connection, it works just fine.
This is my try to use connection strings in Program.cs:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SISTEM_CONTEXT>(
options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});

This is the error in Swagger:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

This works just fine, and the API works
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SISTEM_CONTEXT>(
options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer("server = DESKTOP-RCQQR4T,1433; database = PARTIDOS; user = joacosa; password = 1234xd;TrustServerCertificate=true;");
});

This is my appsettings.json:
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "server = DESKTOP-RCQQR4T,1433; database = PARTIDOS; user = joacosa; password = 1234xd;TrustServerCertificate=true;"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

Full program.cs:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using PARTIDOS_API.Data;
using PARTIDOS_API.Repository;
using PARTIDOS_API.Repository.Interfaces;
using PARTIDOS_API.REPOSITORY;
using PARTIDOS_API.REPOSITORY.Interfaces;
using PARTIDOS_API.TABLAS;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SISTEM_CONTEXT>(
    options =>
    {
        options.UseSqlServer("server = DESKTOP-RCQQR4T,1433; database = PARTIDOS; user = joacosa; password = 1234xd;TrustServerCertificate=true;");
    });


builder.Services.AddTransient<IUsuarioRepository, UsuarioRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ICanchaRepository, CanchaRepository>();       
builder.Services.AddTransient<ICuentaRepository, CuentaRepository>();       
builder.Services.AddTransient<IDireccionRepository, DireccionRepository>(); 
builder.Services.AddTransient<ILocalidadRepository, LocalidadRepository>(); 
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPaisRepository, PaisRepository>();           
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPerfilRepository, PerfilRepository>();       
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPredioRepository, PredioRepository>();       
builder.Services.AddTransient<IProvinciaRepository, ProvinciaRepository>(); 
builder.Services.AddTransient<ITurnoRepository, TurnoRepository>();         
builder.Services.AddTransient<IVinculoRepository, VinculoRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IDiaRepository, DiaRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IHorariosDisponibles, HorariosDisponiblesRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPartidaRepository, PartidaRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPartidaUsuarioRepository, PartidaUsuarioRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IInvitacionRepository, InvitacionRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IDeporteRepository, DeporteRepository>();


builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAnyOrigin",
        builder =>
        {
            builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                   .AllowAnyMethod()
                   .AllowAnyHeader();
        });
});


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseRouting();

// Habilitar CORS
app.UseCors("AllowAnyOrigin");


app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


Is it possible your connection string is being overridden by an appsettings.<env>.json file or user-secrets? What value, if any, does your Configuration.GetConnectionString method resolve?

The error complains that the server is down or the connection string is wrong. It means GetConnectionString worked perfectly and retrieved the connection string. It's not the one you expected though

Put builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") in a separate line and inspect the value. What does it contain? If it's not what you expect, you probably have an appsettings.Development.json or appsettings.Production.json file with a different connection string

That just resolved my problem, it seems that the project was using appsettings.Development.json, but it wasn't "included" in the project itself, so Visual Studio wasn't showing the solution explorer. looking for the file directly in the file explorer i found it.

That file typically appears as a node under appsettings.json, not as a separate file

We are working with github with a friend, and we added appsettings.json to the gitIgnore. Updating the project deleted the file, and probably we added the file by hand to the folder, I think this because I needed to include the file in the ide options to visualize the node

As pointed out by the comments, builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") was working just fine, the problem itself was from where is getting the strings, if you look on program.cs you see it was using Development Enviroment:
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

So it isn't using appsettings.json but instead appsettings.Development.json.
You can find appsettings.Development.json and modify to be the same as appsettings.json, you can find it inside the project folder if the ide is not showing the file.
Other solution could be changing the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable, setting it empty (""), you can find it on the file launchSettings.json, but if you do this, and want to test it with swagger, you need to comment the if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) on program.cs
